# Footer management

Tags: crystal-reports, footer, crystal-reports-2010

I hope I am posting to the right place.
I am relatively new to crystal report and pardon me for any of the "layman's terminology" used here.

Recently my boss asked me to amend 1 of the report in our system. The tasks are as below:

1. Move the page footer to the last page only.

   - I managed to resolve this by inserting " if pagenumber=TotalPageCount then false else true" in the formula workshop in the section expert of the page footer.
2. Make sure the details occupy the blank section leave by the page footer since the page footer is only available in the last page.

   - No Idea

Appreciate if you guys can give some input or workaround to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another solution:

Move the content of `Page Footer` to `Report Footer`.
Report Footer is displayed in the last page.

Suppress `Page Footer` from `Section Expert`.
Details will occupy all page.